# How to return recursive method value in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have java class that will call recursive method for string replace. The method will return the string after replacing all required character one by one. But this not working as expected. Please find the code below.

```
public class TestingRecursion {
    private static String startRecursion(String value){
        value = value.replaceFirst("a", "b");
        if(value.contains("a"))
            startRecursion(value);
        return value;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "1a 2a 3a 4a";

        String afterRecursion = startRecursion(value);
        System.out.println(afterRecursion);
    }
}
```

Expected output - "1b 2b 3b 4b"
Actual output - "1b 2a 3a 4a".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using the return value from startRecursion.

Line 5 should be:

```
    value = startRecursion(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

With the existing linear recursion logic, what you have missed is -

```
if(value.contains("a"))
    return startRecursion(value);
```

It will return the value back.